# Do we have rights to edit the source of the templates which are in wordpress.org?

Tags: themes, copyright

I want know about is, can we edit the source code of themes which can be download in [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/themes/) Do we have rights to edit the source code and, add our own copyright to footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you can find information regarding the license in the `style.css` file located in the root of the theme.

Open it with a text editor (or in the admin panel `Administration > Appearance > Editor`) and check the comment, if it says something like this:

> License: GNU General Public License v3
>
> License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

Then you are free to modify it however you like. If there's no information regarding the license in this file, then check the folder for README file, but in most cases it should be in `style.css`.

I believe that most if not all official Wordpress themes are under GNU license, but it's always better to check your theme before editing it.

Comment: So is it compulsory to mention their names? I mean theme owner's

Comment: It is not compulsory to mention names of the original creators, however it is a good practice to give them a credit. You can do that in the same comment of the `style.css` file. It is compulsory to not change the license though, so make sure that you keep it under GNU. If you wonder whether you can remove their watermark/signature somewhere on the front page (i.e. in the footer), you can remove it or even replace it with yours.

Comment: @VihangaAshinsana, please don't forget to accept my answer if it satisfies your question, otherwise feel free to ask for details.